# Optional returning nil even though it contains non-nil value

Tags: ios, swift, enums, protocols

I have an `customStringConvertible` enum I used to model data that will be used for collectionViewCells. The Data is intended to be retrieved at cellForItemAt. The Data is not being retrieved.

Made a protocol to attach gettable vars to the enum.

Initialized the var and value returns nil even tho the print statement shows intended values.

Update***
I restructured my data into a class and added them to an Array. And I solved the problem by adding line of code into the database retrieval function as follows:

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   //collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

I entered the code right after the completion of the if let statement. I left the code below as is. Put the Database code into its own separate function, embedding in the viewDidLoad function of the corresponding controller.

```swift
var name: String {
        var name:String?
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                name = dictionary["firstName"] as? String
                print(String(describing: name))
            }
        }, withCancel: nil)
        return name ?? "Does not Work"
    }
```

The expected results are to show the snapshot value when the `var` name is called for a reusable cell's property instead of `"Does not Work"`

Comment: The `return name ?? "Does not Work"` line is called long before you set name inside the asynchronous completion block.

Comment: @rmaddy what would be the appropriate way to format my initializer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should move the async block to another function, then you update the name after its value gets fetched, as @rmaddy has pointed out that `return name ?? "Does not Work"` has been called before the async block is complete.

```
    func updateName() {
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                    name = dictionary["firstName"] as? String
                    // update the new name to your model and update your label with the new name
                }
            }, withCancel: nil)
    }
```

You can also use a callback to update UI after the name is fetched:

```
    func updateName(callback: (String) -> ()) {
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                    name = dictionary["firstName"] as? String
                    // update the new name to your model and update your label with the new name
                    // call the callback function
                    callback(name)
                }
            }, withCancel: nil)
    }
```

Call updateName function from outside:

```
updateName() { (name) in
    label.text = name
}
```

Comment: I'm using an enum as datasource for collectionViewCells. If I try to use the function to return a string, I have the same issue.

Comment: I don't think a function which returns a string directly would be suitable in this case. Instead, you can pass a callback to the function so the callback is called after the name is fetched. See my edited answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I explained well. The label is apart of a collectionViewCell that I'm reusing. I made a customStringConvertible enum as the datasource to populate the cells. The var I displayed above represents one row of data. Would this still be a practical solution to my issue?

Comment: From my experience, I normally use enum for cell types or categories. I'm not sure why you want to use an enum here, as it can't have a stored property. In this case you can a struct for your modal. However, to build a datasource for cells in table view or collection view, I prefer class as it is reference type. In either case, you can just put the updateName function in the model class/struct, and call it when you populate your cells. I don't know if it solves your issue.

Comment: I made a class and tried to use an initializer to get the values and made a separate function to execute retrieval but I'm having the same issue. The data needs to be there when the view loads which is why I'm having so much difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, you're trying to access a variable that it's value actually dependent on the completion-handler inside of it.

Therefore the application is giving you nil **sometimes** when the completion-handler did not trigger, on the other hand in debugging you can see a value, because the value now exists, but the problem is the complier could now be reading other lines of codes, and it doesn't know that the value is now here.

By other words : You're trying to access some value that you fetch from somewhere, and while you're waiting that value to return, and use it properly, the compiler is now reading something else on another thread.

What you're missing is a completion-handler that actually triggers the value of that variable when it comes from where you fetch it therefore forcing the compiler to go back and read it, when it triggers.

> **Note :** I recommend reading [this](https://medium.com/@nimjea/completion-handler-in-swift-4-2-671f12d33178) article about completion-handlers and how they actually function in swift .

**How to fix your case:**

Since you're using `enum`, and you want the fetching function inside the variable it self for some reason you can only fix this by creating a critical section with `DispatchSemaphores`.

I created a small demo for you to understand how it works, and i also recommend [this](https://medium.com/swiftly-swift/a-quick-look-at-semaphores-6b7b85233ddb) article.

**Demo:**

```
 var name: String {
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    var name = "no value"
        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
            name = "new Value"
            semaphore.signal()
    }
    semaphore.wait()
    return name
}
```

Your code should be something like this .

```
  var name: String {
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
        var name:String?
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                name = dictionary["firstName"] as? String
                print(String(describing: name))
                semaphore.signal() // signal when i get the new value
            }
        }, withCancel: nil)
        semaphore.wait() // wait till signal
        return name ?? "Does not Work"
    }
```

> Beware this is the only way for your case, and it's not recommended, i do
>   recommend change your structure, because you will be freezing the
>   application 'till you get the data, and that it bad .

Comment: what would your suggestion be for modeling the data? I chose an enum that subclasses customStringConvertibles because I made a collectionView with simple cells. Each row of data is it's own reusable cell.

Comment: Struct is an option

Comment: So I took your advice and made a class of type NSObject. Everything works except, I still can't get the collection view to reload once the data is retrieved. 
I tried to dispatch

```swift
dispatch.main.async {
    self.profileDescription.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I made a for in loop for my array but when I populate my cells, they all display the last element in array
```swift
for item in profileData {
                cell.descriptionLabel.text = item
                print("data here is \(item)")
            }
```